# How to split a string with Java regex including a variable-width delimiter in the resulting list

Tags: java, regex, string

I would like to split a string into quoted and unquoted parts, in which escaped quotes are ignored. For example, the following input:

```
String input = "Example with \"quoted \\\"test\\\" region\" embedded";
```

Should result in the following list:

```
String[] result = ["Example with", "\"quoted \\\"test\\\" region\"", "embedded"];
```

For splitting quoted regions (while ignoring escaped quotes) I use:

```
public static final String QUOTE_PATTERN = "(?<!\\\\)\".*?(?<!\\\\)\"";

String input = "Example with \"quoted \\\"test\\\" region\" embedded";
String[] result = input.split(QUOTE_PATTERN);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

Which provides the expected output `[Example with ,  embedded]`. However, I would very much like to have the delimiters (the quoted regions) in this list as well. (Of course, I can achieve this by getting the start stop indices using a Matcher, but that still requires a lot of extra code.)

I found a solution to split a string including the delimiters by using a lookahead and lookbehind which can successfully split a colon-separated string into a list that also contains the colons:

```
public static final String WITH_DELIMITER = "((?<=%1$s)|(?=%1$s))";
public static final String COLON_PATTERN = String.format(WITH_DELIMITER, ":");

String colonTest = "Part0:Part1:Part2";
String[] parts = colonTest.split(COLON_PATTERN);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

This provides the following output: `[Part0, :, Part1, :, Part2]`.

However, it seems that this cannot be applied to delimiters with a variable length, because:

```
public static final String WITH_DELIMITER = "((?<=%1$s)|(?=%1$s))";
public static final String QUOTE_PATTERN = 
    String.format(WITH_DELIMITER, "(?<!\\\\)\".*?(?<!\\\\)\"");

String input = "Example with \"quoted \\\"test\\\" region\" embedded";
String[] result = input.split(QUOTE_PATTERN);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

throws the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length near index 23
((?<=(?<!\\)".*?(?<!\\)")|(?=(?<!\\)".*?(?<!\\)"))
                   ^
```

Does anyone know if something similar is possible for variable-width delimiters?

Thanks!

Comment: java won't support variable length lookbehind.

Comment: Java supports constrained look-behind. What is the maximum length you expect in the look-behind and look-ahead? Try `String.format(WITH_DELIMITER, "(?<!\\\\)\".{0,1000}(?<!\\\\)\"");` if you expect the string of maximum 1000 symbols in length. [Have a look at this code](https://ideone.com/syCByd).

Comment: @Tomalak No that's wrong. That's a Java string so the first escape character is for the literal string. The resulting literal Java will work with is: `Example with "quoted \"test\" region" embedded`

Comment: Ah, of course. Didn't look at it that way.

Comment: @stribizhev Tanks! That works like a charm! And 1000 symbols is more than enough, I reduced it to 200, wich is sufficient for my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your strings are not longer than 200 symbols long, you can make use of the Java [constrained-width look-behind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookbehind_width), i.e. Java's look-behind supports `{0,200}` quantifiers (where min and max lengths are specified).

> ✽ Java accepts quantifiers within lookbehind, as long as the length of the matching strings falls within a pre-determined range. For instance, `(?<=cats?)` is valid because it can only match strings of three or four characters. Likewise, `(?<=A{1,10})` is valid.

Thus, you can leverage this code:

```
String.format(WITH_DELIMITER, "(?<!\\\\)\".{0,200}(?<!\\\\)\"");
                                           ^^^^^^^
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/syCByd)

```
   String WITH_DELIMITER = "((?<=%1$s)|(?=%1$s))";
   String QUOTE_PATTERN = 
   String.format(WITH_DELIMITER, "(?<!\\\\)\".{0,200}(?<!\\\\)\"");

   String input = "Example with \"quoted \\\"test\\\" region\" embedded";
   String[] result = input.split(QUOTE_PATTERN);
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

Output:

```
[Example with , "quoted \"test\" region",  embedded]
```

Answer (score 0):

Look aheads/behinds are slower but tend to be more easily understandable. You can accomplish the same thing if you take the time to understand a simple optional capture:

```
(?:[^\\"]|\\.)*
```

The first option says to match anything that is *not* a backslash or quotation mark character. The second option says to match *any* escaped character.

When used with the asterisks this will capture anything up to a non-escaped quotation mark.

Now lets use that information in a regex:

```
((?:[^\\"]|\\.)*)("(?:[^\\"]|\\.)*")
```

This will first capture your preceding string and then capture your quoted string with the quotation marks.

If you want to just capture everything else up to the end of the line you could add a `(.*)` to the end of the regex. But you could also just expand that regex to deal with more than one quoted string on a line.